Live Action Fairy Tale Movie with Old Woman Who Lives in a Shoe
I'm trying to remember the name of a movie I watched during my childhood.  Here's what I remember:

It was a live-action movie
Most/all the characters were based on fairy tales
One of the characters was 'The Old Woman Who Lives in a Shoe'.  She wasn't the leading character, but I think she had an important role.
Near the end of the movie, after the conflict has been resolved, all of the characters are standing outside the Old Woman's house (a giant shoe) and celebrating.
I saw it on US television when I was a child, in the mid-to-late 90's.  It didn't seem terribly old.  For some reason I think it was a made-for-TV movie (or series??)

I went through The Definitive List of Live-Action Fairy Tale Movies, but didn't see anything that looked familiar.  I've also been googling for days, with no luck.

Oi, of course as soon as I post this I find the answer.  It was Mother Goose Rock 'n' Rhyme (1990)
I found it through this page.
